# How to detect if selected text is bold?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, spannablestring

I am creating a rich text box in Xamarin.Android. So far I can make the selected text into bold or italic text. However, now I want, when clicking on the bold button, then the selected text should turn back to normal. So my question is, how do I check if the selected text is bold?
   I have tried following way

```
 void bButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var richEditText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.richEditText);


        SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(richEditText.Text);

        string selected = sb.SubSequenceFormatted(richEditText.SelectionStart, richEditText.SelectionEnd).ToString();

        if(selected == Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Bold) // It,s not working.
        So please suggest  me how to check selected text is bold or not

        following line for to make bold

        sb.SetSpan(new StyleSpan(Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Bold), richEditText.SelectionStart, richEditText.SelectionEnd,0);


        richEditText.TextFormatted = sb;
```

Comment: Why did you revert the edit I made? It is back to poor grammar, bad formatting and missing tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you cannot ask a `String` object whether it is a `Enum`.

Something like this works:

```
button.Click += (sender, args) =>
{
    var start = editText.SelectionStart;
    var end = editText.SelectionEnd;

    if (start > end)
    {
        var temp = end;
        end = start;
        start = temp;
    }

    var ss = (ISpannable)editText.TextFormatted;

    // get all spannables in selection, there could be multiple
    var spans = ss.GetSpans(start, end, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(StyleSpan)));

    var exists = false;

    // loop over all spans
    foreach (var t in spans)
    {
        var style = ((StyleSpan)t).Style;

        // if one of the spans is bold
        if (style == TypefaceStyle.Bold)
        {
            // remove the span
            ss.RemoveSpan(t);
            exists = true;
        }
    }

    // if none of the spannables were bold, lets make it bold
    if (!exists)
        ss.SetSpan(new StyleSpan(TypefaceStyle.Bold), start, end, 0);
};
```

So basically what I am doing in the code above is to check all `Spannable` instances in the selection to see if their `Style` is `TypefaceStyle.Bold`. The casting is pretty naive though, so be careful with that.

Comment: @ Cheesedaron yes, you are right. I intentionally add this line to understand because I was confuse about that issue. But u solve this very well. Thank you.